# Google Drive php API V3: Can't search folder with cyrillic name

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

9 months ago a I wrote a little project and one of it's features was to search a specific folder in google drive's root or inner folder and return its id. The folder name can be Latin or Cyrillic. Until July or August 2017 everything worked fine, but since two months it started to return empty array when I trying to search folders with Cyrillic names and created recently (younger 2 months). If I create folder with Latin name - all works fine.

This is my old code for searching in drive's root:

```
$driveService->files->listFiles([
                'q' => "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and 'root' in parents and name = 'Новая Папка' and trashed = false"
            ]);
```

This doesn't work. If I create folder named 'New Folder' everything works fine without changes.

But if I change 'name =' to 'name contains'

```
$driveService->files->listFiles([
                'q' => "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and 'root' in parents and name contains 'Новая Папка' and trashed = false"
            ]);
```

Everything works perfectly. But this code is dangerous - I expect, that code will return only one folder, but if near this folder will be created folders with names 'Новая папка 1', 'Новая папка 2', 'Новая папка 10' etc..

Google API V3 docs says to use 'name =' to search exact name, so I'm stumped.

Comment: Ran into the same problem today when using the drive SDK for android. Currently we are discussing to use the contains filter and filter the results further afterwards. IMHO this should be fixed by Google.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out this is a known [bug in the Google Drive APIs documented here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64468406).

For now the workaround is to use the contains filter and manually look for the correct result afterwards like this:

```
getFileByName(name) {
  files = GoogleDriveAPI.searchFiles('title contains "%name"')
  for(file in files) {
    if(file.getName() === name)
        return file
  }
  return null
}
```